# removing file versions from the file

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I am trying to write down the powershell script which should remove the item version or language version "en" from all the files located in folder tour, if it finds "Title" section in the file.

My script is working only on top file name in the loop whose title is empty but not on other files in the loop whose title are empty as well. How can I change this script so that it can scroll through out the loop and remove the language version from each of these different files whose title is empty?

```
$SN1 = Get-ItemProperty -Path "master:/content/www/home/company/tour/*"  -Name "Title" 

$SN2 = ''

$SN3 = 
 foreach ($SItem in $SN1.Title) {

     if ("$SItem" -eq $SN2)
     {
        Remove-ItemVersion  -Path "master:/content/www/home/company/tour/*" -Language "en"
     }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your basic syntax skills may need some additional study as for some reason you have quotes around the variable you are testing and are incorrectly using syntax for the title.

So first of all, change:

```
 if ("$SItem" -eq $SN2)
```

To:

```
 if (!($SItem))
```

Then, SN1 is ONLY the title as you have it written, so trying to do $SN1.title simply won't work.  Also, what is the source you are querying?

EDIT:  ANSWER BELOW:

Now that you provided the object type it is clear.  Here is the code but you need to verify WHAT is getting deleted is the correct key/value:

```
$SN1 = Get-ItemProperty -Path "master:/content/www/home/company/tour/*" -Name "Title"    
if ($SN1.Title -eq '')
{
    Remove-ItemVersion -Path "master:/content/www/home/company/tour/*" -Language "en"       
}
```

Unless I am missing something, based on the Get-Member $SN1 is a SINGLE item so there is no need to loop anything.  If there are more than one somewhere, I have not seen indication  in your code so you will need to provide more detail.  This command reads the single Title, and if it is blank, go delete something else.  For a COLLECTION of Titles, you need to provide where they live etc. for more help.

Comment: Correct because your syntax is incorrect.  Can you possibly paste the output of the following command for me?:  

$SN1 = Get-ItemProperty -Path "master:/content/www/home/company/tour/*"  -Name "Title"
$SN1 | GM

Sorry this site's comments friggin wrap that is 2 commands above your original 1st line to define $SN1, then run the 2nd command which is piping $SN1 | Get-Member

Comment: You need to run the command I asked for pipe the $SN1 to get-member i need to see what kind of object that is returning then I can help you with the correct code.  Those below posting code I can tell you is not correct because they also have no idea what the object types are being returned so they are guessing.  Run:  "$SN1 | Get-member" and post the output please

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the path you are selecting, Get-ItemProperty cannot use an * in its path to select every item in the path. You must get the items first and then pipe them into the Get-ItemProperty.

You need to create an array of every item and its properties and then loop through those.

```
$SN1 = Get-ChildItem -Path ""master:/content/www/home/company/tour" | Get-ItemProperty | select *
```

Then loop through each item:

```
 $DebugPreference = 'Continue'
 foreach ($SItem in $SN1) 
 {
     Write-Debug -Message "Checking item $($SItem.Name) for a title."
     if(!($SItem.Title))
     {
        Write-Debug -Message "A title does not exist for this item $($SItem.FullName), removing the language property of its ItemVersion."
        Remove-ItemVersion -Path $SItem.FullName -Language "en"
     }

 }
```

As a note you'll want to use -Recurse on the Get-ChildItem if you have subdirectories you want to search through as well.

Comment: @user7986299 I updated the code, there was an error, it should be .FullName, instead of .FullPath.

Comment: You'll have to post the code to the Remove-ItemVersion, that is not a native Powershell command that I'm familiar with. There's a possibility it's expecting something different than the path we are providing it or additional parameters are required. Also, you should add debugging messages to aid in knowing what your code is doing. I've added examples above.